# How to detect missing year in time series data in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

Let's say we have column with the following years:

```
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022
```

Now I need a code which will identify which years is missing (2016 in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setdiff()`.

```r
setdiff(seq(min(x), max(x)), x)
# [1] 2016
```

###### Data

```r
x <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022)
```

---

###### Update

According to the additional request, the code could be extended as

```r
yr <- setdiff(seq(min(x), max(x)), x)
if( !length(yr) ) yr <- "no year is missing"
```

***Note:*** If `yr` is of length 0, `!length(yr)` will gets `TRUE`.

Comment: If there is no missing year, I want to get "no year is missing", is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in `base` R:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022))
all_years <- seq(min(df$year), max(df$year))
result <- all_years[!all_years %in% df$year]
result
[1] 2016

if(lenth(result) == 0) result <- "no year is missing"
```

Comment: If there is no missing year, I want to get "no year is missing", is that possible?

Comment: Added final line

Comment: I think there is needed if..else statement, no?

Comment: Only if required here if you store in one single variable

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to know which year is missing?

If so, you can try with :

```
all_years <- seq(2012, 2022, 1)
years_in_column <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022)

all_years[!all_years %in% years_in_column]
```

Comment: If there is no missing year, I want to get "no year is missing", is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdiff`:

```
years <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022)
all_years <- seq(min(years), max(years))
setdiff(all_years, years)
#> [1] 2016
```